# Routing issues with Post in Form

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

Error with Post Route in form. Post clicking on "submit" button its taking me to page.

```
 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
    in RouteCollection.php line 161
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 780
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Create.Blade.PHP. i also wanted to know if the method is properly defined.

```
<form action="POST" method="/users">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

  Name:<input type="text" name="name"></br>
  Email:<input type="text" name="email"></br>
  Password:<input type="text" name="password"></br>
  Submit:<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Routing File

```
Route::GET('/', function () {
    return View('hello');
});

Route::get('users/create',['uses'=>'UsersController@create']);
Route::post('users',['uses'=>'UsersController@store']);
```

Checked the registered routes "php artisan route:list -v" Shows both the routes have been properly registered.

UsersController.PHP

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $users=[
      '0'=>[
      'name'=>'arun',
      'email'=>'ak@gmail.com',
      'location'=>'india'],
      '1'=>[
      'name'=>'kaushik',
      'email'=>'arunk@gmail.com',
      'location'=>'india'],
    ];

      return View('admin.users.index',Compact('users'));
    }


     public function create()
    {
      return View('admin.users.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
   {
     return $request->all();

   }
}
```

Lastly,I dint make any changes to .htaccess file,this is a new installation .
I have properly run PHP artisan migrations successfully.

Comment: change your <form action="POST" method="/users"> to <form action="/users" method="POST">

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just switched the action and method attribute of your form.

```
<form action="POST" method="/users">
 {{ csrf_field() }}

  Name:<input type="text" name="name"></br>
  Email:<input type="text" name="email"></br>
  Password:<input type="text" name="password"></br>
  Submit:<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```